# onclick image is not getting

Tags: javascript, jquery

hi i add a image inside the tr dynamically now i want to call a function when i click this image iuse this code

```js
 $("#tabletask tr[data-id='" + parrentid + "'] > td:first-child").html(" <img src=\"Images/ExpandArrow.png\">" + OriginalContent)

   $(document).on('click', 'image.ExpandArrow', function () {....});
```

but its not working

Comment: i think it shud be img in 'image.ExpandArrow ? :)

Comment: Because your selector is wrong .

Comment: try  
 $(document).on('click', 'img', function () {....});

Comment: @ vignesh i try  "img"  but no change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var img = $("<img>", {src: "/path/to/img"});

$("#tabletask tr[data-id='" + parrentid + "'] > td:first-child").appendChild(img);
img.onclick = functionName;
```

where `functionName` is the function you want to happen when it's clicked.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `img.ExpandArrow` and not `image.ExpandArrow`.

use this also `$("#tabletask")`

```js
 $("#tabletask tr[data-id='" + parrentid + "'] > td:first-child").html(" <img src=\"Images/ExpandArrow.png\">" + OriginalContent)

   $("#tabletask").on('click', 'img.ExpandArrow', function () {....});
```

Comment: @Shlomi There is no class named `ExpandArrow ` so this `img.ExpandArrow ` will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving a **class to that image and try to bind the class to the document**.

```
$("#tabletask tr[data-id='" + parrentid + "'] > td:first-child")
 .html(" <img class = 'image' src=\"Images/ExpandArrow.png\">" + OriginalContent)
```

`$(document).on('click', '.image', function () {....});`